# access virtual server on WLAN

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine, home-networking

I'm hosting a Virtual Server that I'd like to be able to access over my WLAN at home. Currently, I can access the virtual server from the host machine running it. But how could another computer access the virtual server over my network?

The Guest OS is on UbuntuServer(64)12.04
The host is Windows 7(64) Home Prem
And I'm using Virtual Box as my VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the host, add hardware> (already connected) press a > "add a new hardware device"> click "install manually from a list"> click "network adapters",Click Microsoft>..MS Loopback Adapter..> finished (almost) next ICS...
2. search or open "Network connections" from control panel rt-click Physical Adapter>Properties>Advanced>check.. Allow other network users to connect through this computer’s internet connection {OK}
3. open Virtual Machine’s settings
   Set its Network Connection to Use your new Microsoft Loopback Adapter.

There may be a wizard for this. search virtual loopback

HTH's
Tony

Comment: When I follow these steps I end up having no internet connectivity. 
I am still connected to my wireless internet, as well as the loopback adapter. In the loopback adapter properties I had sharing set to allow users to connect through my wireless network connection. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.